# MongoDB aggregation: Simple way to check if an array of numbers contains a negative number

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let say I have an array like so: `[2,4,-6,-7,-3,5]`.

Is there a simple(not verbose) way of checking if an array contains a negative number in mongodb aggregation.

I will appreciate any answer. Even one that is verbose. I just prefer a less verbose one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just filter docs that have an array-property that contains a negative number, a simple `{ arrayField: { $lt: 0 } }` would do.

Also if you just want to somehow categorize an array in aggregation, you could do the following.

For example, documents with schema:

```js
{
  _id: 1,
  values: [2, -4, -6, -7]
}
```

you can add an extra **boolean** `negative` field on the documents and filter according to that later on in aggregation results:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      negative: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$values",
          initialValue: false,
          in: {
            $or: ["$$value", { $lt: ["$$this",0] }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Also added extra information about aggregation pipeline

Comment: Number 0 is not negative but yields to `false`. Apart from that, nice and short solution

Comment: You are right, I remebered the question wrongly when I added my second implementation. This is not correct. Will fix the answer to be correct for the given example